# get current page url in keycloak email template

Tags: keycloak, freemarker

I want to get the current page url in keycloak email template. I have made a custom template for emails. If you check their repository especially [this line](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/eb77dcf0140023591ecacc351212f15190147e4a/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/email/html/password-reset.ftl#L3), you can see link parameter. So the link parameter would look something like http://example.com/realms/master/login-actions/action-token?key=somekey... I got that and by doing some stuff I can get the url (http://example.com). But the link parameter only works for reset password email template. If I want to send a success email once the user has successfully changed the password, I have to use [this file](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/eb77dcf0140023591ecacc351212f15190147e4a/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/email/html/event-update_password.ftl). Now in there I can't use link parameter so I can't get any url.

I'm using FreeMarker(ftl). There is redirectUri on the localstorage, it can be helpful if I can get that in the email templates.

[redirect uri in localstorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1W3w.png)

Here is an example of the password-reset.ftl

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.emailLayout>
${kcSanitize(msg("eventUpdatePasswordBodyHtml",event.date, event.ipAddress))?no_esc}

<#--  this is how I get the domain output: http://example.com/realms/master/login-actions/action-token?key=somekey...  -->
${link}
</@layout.emailLayout>
```

event-update_password.ftl

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.emailLayout>
${kcSanitize(msg("eventUpdatePasswordBodyHtml",event.date, event.ipAddress))?no_esc}

<#--  can't use ${link} here  -->
</@layout.emailLayout>
```